# php design pattern for big project and for small project

Tags: php, frameworks

hi firends can anyone explain me which one is best design pattern for big projects and which one for small projects i dont want to use a framework i am trying to create simple design and big framework

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Design patterns are not universal solutions for all problems. Every design patterns is suitable to be applied in certain situation and to resolve certain problem with particular results.

So, your answer is a non-sense. There is no "best design pattern" in general. It depends what do you need the pattern for. In additional in general the design patterns are not specific for a given technology, framework or programming language. It's uncommon to see design pattern for `<insert programming language here>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre defined design pattern for small or big project, It all depends on how easy it for you to use the conventions and how fast and easily you can learn and remember them.
You can use the **conventions over configurations** to make you design more readable and easy or any other way you want.

Well i personally feel, [Zend conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) are good.

Thanks